# Ejercicio de manipulación en listas Python

Tags: python

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo python y en este ejercicio en especifico (Encontrar la desviacion tipica) me encontre con un problema que no me deja avanzar.

La variable promedio tiene un valor de 15.6 despues de la ejecución del código,  entonces mi problema en concreto radica cuando tengo que restar a cada elemento de la lista el promedio, puesto que el resultado para el primer dato siempre me da como resultado 0.

```
media = (lista[j] - promedio)
```

Resultados esperados

```
La media para el dato  1 es :  -10.6
La media para el dato  2 es :  -0.6
La media para el dato  3 es :  -3.6
La media para el dato  4 es :   2.4
La media para el dato  5 es :   12.4
```

Resultados obtenidos

```
La media para el dato  1 es :  0.0
La media para el dato  2 es :  5.0
La media para el dato  3 es :  1.333333333333334
La media para el dato  4 es :  5.5
La media para el dato  5 es :  12.4
```

Adjunto codigo, cualquier consejo o pista sera de gran ayuda.
De antemano gracias

```py
lista = [5, 15, 12, 18, 28]

i = 0
x = 0
y = 0
j = 0
sumatoria = 0
promedio = 0
elevado = 0
sumatoria_cuadrado = 0
media = 0

for x in range(len(lista)):
    sumatoria = sumatoria + lista[i]
    i = i + 1
    promedio = sumatoria/i

    media = lista[j] - promedio                              #Problema
    j = j + 1
    print("La media para el dato ", i, "es : ", media)
```

Comment: ¿Qué parte del código no funciona?

Comment: @eyllanesc Las 3 ultimas lineas de codigo, siempre obtengo en la variable media para el primer elemento de la lista "0" como resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable "sumatoria" se va construyendo en el loop por lo que su valor no puede ser usado dentro del loop para calcular el promedio. Si quieres calcular el promedio debes sumar todos los elementos y dividirlo entre la cantidad de elementos por lo que puedes usar un loop para ello:

```py
suma = 0
for elemento in lista:
    suma += elemento
promedio = suma / len(lista)
```

O usar la función sum:

```py
promedio = sum(lista) / len(lista)
```

Entonces debes crear otro loop para calcular la desviación estandar o típica:

```py
for elemento in lista:
    media = elemento - promedio
```

---

Al final el código seria el siguiente:

```py
lista = [5, 15, 12, 18, 28]

promedio = sum(lista) / len(lista)

for i, elemento in enumerate(lista):
    media = elemento - promedio
    print("La media para el dato {} es {:.1f}".format(i, media))
```